# Websocket session disconnect on connection loss using ping/pong

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, spring-websocket

I have a spring boot project in which I have implemented web sockets. I have not  used STOMP, instead, I have implemented a **`TextWebSocketHandler`** which handles  all the messages.

---

In order to handle session disconnection on network failure, I have made used of the ping pong scheme as follows as suggested in this thread [handling-connection-loss-with-websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971026/handling-connection-loss-with-websockets)

- There is a periodic task which sends **`PingMessage`** to each **`WebSocketSession`**. I keep a flag for each session which indicates whether a pong has been received or not.
- Before sending the ping message, I check whether I have received the pong for the previously sent ping, if not, then I close the session using the **`close()`** method of the **`WebSocketSession`** class
- Upon receiving the pong message, I update the flag for the session

---

Now the problem is when I try to close a session, then other sessions are also being closed. I added some logs int the **`afterConnectionClosed()`** callback, and I can see that it is being triggered for sessions other than the one on which I called **`close()`** method.

I am not sure why this is happening.

Also, is there any other way by which I can handle connection loss in web sockets

---

The following is some information related to versions

- Spring boot version **1.5.10.RELEASE**
- JDK **1.8**

Comment: Are you developing both the server and the client?

Comment: I am developing just the server. The clients are mobile apps and a web app which is  not a part of this spring project