# Websocket establish bulletproof connection

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket, coffeescript

My coffee code to establish websocket connection when it isn't present return an error:

```
socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')
#=> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/.
#=> socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
```

It's normal behaviour of WebSocket, but I want WebSockets work like this:

```
# pseudocode
if websocket.establish_connection()
  # do thing #1
else
  do thing no.2
```

I think about `try`...`catch` but I think it's dirty. Is there any other way of troubleshooting?

Comment: there is some `readyState` property, maybe this helps  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809267/how-do-i-know-if-connection-is-alive-with-websockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not actually throwing an Error, the program execution continues. Its simply  logging the error (asynchronously) to the console. To handle connection failures, you can bind to the sockets `onerror` event.

Something like this could work:

```js
function establishWSConnection(url) {
    return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
        var ws = new WebSocket(url);
        ws.onerror = rej;
        ws.onopen = function () {
            ws.onerror = null;
            res(ws);
        }
    });
}

establishWSConnection('ws://localhost:1234').then(function(ws) {
    // do stuff
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```