# Can a WebSocket connection be disconnected or messages lost due to poor signal strength?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have an app that uses native WebSockets on the browser and [node ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) on the server.  I have been testing it on devices that do not have great Wi-Fi connections (on  a five bar signal strength indicator they will range from two to five bars).

It seems that this really impacts performance.  When a device has two or so bars, it looks like messages aren't transmitted to / received from the server. I can't really check to see if the connection has been dropped because of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809267/how-do-i-know-if-connection-is-alive-with-websockets) but it doesn't seem right that just because a device has a weak signal, that messages would not transmit.  Because they are based on TCP, **don't WebSockets guarantee delivery of messages / and wouldn't a connection persist as long as there is any internet connectivity?**

Comment: Only if the TCP connection itself lasts. Even if there technically is a connection, it might be so bad the TCP driver just gives up. Or it keeps trying to transmit the same message from two hours ago.

Comment: So if I send a basic message, for instance I press a button that sends "hello", then I press a button that says "hi", will "hello" always be sent before "hi"? (Is there some sort of queue?)